# How can I use cbgreek with lualatex?

Tags: luatex, cbgreek

With pdflatex, this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=british,polutonikogreek]{babel}
\begin{document}
{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}
οὔ μοι τὰ Γύγεω τοῦ πολυχρύσου μέλει,}
he said
\end{document}
```

yields the expected, and I suppose the Greek font is cbgreek.
But with lualatex, the Greek disappears.  What must I change to
get the same output with lualatex as with pdflatex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For small inserts in Greek, assuming you don't need correct hyphenation, the workaround of changing `inputenc` into `luainputenc` might do.

For more intensive usage of Greek, you should consider switching to `fontspec`. The CM-Unicode fonts incorporate the CB Greek fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=british,greek.polutoniko]{babel}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{greek}{οὔ μοι τὰ Γύγεω τοῦ πολυχρύσου μέλει},
he said

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` with `LuaLaTeX`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=british,polutonikogreek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}
οὔ μοι τὰ Γύγεω τοῦ πολυχρύσου μέλει,}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would explain the use of the `luainputenc` and `fontenc` package

Comment: Remove the call to inputenc, that does nothing

Comment: @ilFuria [`luainputenc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luainputenc)  and [`fontenc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc)

Comment: Note that while this does make greek letters appear using 8-bt fonts  with luatex is generally not the recommended approach (and will give incorrect hyphenation without more work)

Comment: @Sebastiano yes, of course one can look up the documentation, I just thought it would be nice to have (directly in the answer) the explanation on why one has to use them to obtain the result.

Comment: @ilFuria I do not know what to tell you more. I added, looking at the two manuals, the two lines to see the Greek characters.

Comment: Don't use fontenc with lualatex!!!